# Compiled typescript scripts has a " ; "

Tags: typescript

this is the sample. as you can see, there is a semicolon in `new (): T`

#### Source script:

```
public myFunction<T extends FunctionA>(param: { new (): T }): T
```

#### Compiled script:

```
myFunction<T extends FunctionA>(param: { new (): T; }): T;
```

I don't know why it has comma, and it cause an error in my code when I used the compiled one.

Comment: That does not look like compiled ts. Compiled ts should have all the types removed `myFunction` still has types. There might be another error somewhere tripping up the compiler or you are not looking at the right file

Comment: Welcome to [so]! That does definitely not look like ts-compiled code. Looks like a problem I've seen when your IDE tries to auto fix broken code with `tslint`.

Answer (score -1):

```
public myFunction<T extends FunctionA>(param: { new (): T }): T
```

shouldn't it be like

```
public myFunction<T extends FunctionA>(param: { ctor: () => T }): T
```

Because as I understand you are truing to pass non-parametric constructor of `T` to the function?

Comment: Compiled TypeScript shouldn't even have types in it. There's something wrong in the way his build is producing the output.